# Modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous

Since I created a readJson method I have this error:

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100731d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001024d8deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100731cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x0000000100cadb6b _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
4   Foundation                          0x0000000100b0d357 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 31
5   UIKit                               0x0000000101850adb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
6   UIKit                               0x0000000101850477 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 646
7   UIKit                               0x0000000101850ae4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 67
8   UIKit                               0x00000001018501ac -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 242
9   UIKit                               0x0000000101005538 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 113
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101005461 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 544
11  UIKit                               0x000000010101326c -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1967
12  MacCRM                              0x0000000100471a40 _TFE6MacCRMCSo6UIViewP33_0AB6F1737B613FE8A7F8E017F6C0671E9showToastfT5toastS0_8durationSd8positionPs9AnyObject__T_ + 1296
13  MacCRM                              0x000000010046e8bc _TFE6MacCRMCSo6UIView9makeToastfT7messageSS8durationSd8positionPs9AnyObject__T_ + 428
14  MacCRM                              0x0000000100471ee3 _TToFE6MacCRMCSo6UIView9makeToastfT7messageSS8durationSd8positionPs9AnyObject__T_ + 99
15  MacCRM                              0x000000010046e688 _TFE6MacCRMCSo6UIView9makeToastfT7messageSS_T_ + 136
16  MacCRM                              0x000000010046e6f8 _TToFE6MacCRMCSo6UIView9makeToastfT7messageSS_T_ + 72
17  MacCRM                              0x000000010049c176 _TFFFC6MacCRM7Ajustes7guardarFPs9AnyObject_T_U_FT_T_U_FTGSqCSo6NSData_GSqCSo13NSURLResponse_GSqCSo7NSError__T_ + 7462
18  MacCRM                              0x000000010048c0a7 _TTRXFo_oGSqCSo6NSData_oGSqCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSqCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSqS__dGSqS0__dGSqS1___dT__ + 103
19  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103a17b49 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
20  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103a2a0f2 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 302
21  Foundation                          0x0000000100bac630 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
22  Foundation                          0x0000000100ae7805 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
23  Foundation                          0x0000000100aca725 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 646
24  Foundation                          0x0000000100aca336 __NSOQSchedule_f + 194
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102f6e3eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102f5482c _dispatch_queue_drain + 2215
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102f53d4d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 601
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102f56996 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1420
29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102f56405 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001032c24de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001032c0341 start_wqthread + 13
```

I know what is the problem and reading looking I have to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {` I call my method inside but still have the problem. Some idea?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Solved

The problem was my toast library.

Comment: post your code here then only others can check whats wrong with it

Comment: I think the problem is that you get data in the main thread, which makes an asynchronous thread is created. So when you modify the values of view, it is not in the main thread.

You should get data outside from main thread, and inside you perform only update data.

Comment: u r missing some objects to keep in main Queue in ur code . try to post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. You are using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {...
```

Before starting the dataTask, the dataTask will run asynchronously, that being, since the dataTask will work asynchronously, the closure will be executed in a background thread.

You can fix it by removing the line:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

from where it is and then adding it inside the completion block, if you have it like this:

```
...{ data, response, error in
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

it will work fine.

But you should only call the main thread when the computing operation is done, so that the hard part is done by a background thread.